# how to execute dynamic values in JS

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var widgetsBelow=[{
        "name": "alfresco/renderers/CustomProperty",
        "config": {
            "label": "Product Title",
            "propertyToRender": "node.properties.cbib:title"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "alfresco/renderers/CustomProperty",
        "config": {
            "label": "Author",
            "propertyToRender": "node.properties.cbib:author"
        }
    }
];

var currentItem=[{
        "name": "alfresco/renderers/CustomProperty",
        "node": {
            "properties": {
                "cbib:title": "product title"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "alfresco/renderers/CustomProperty",
        "node": {
            "properties": {
                "cbib:author": "author"
            }
        }
    }
];

            for(var i=0;i<this.widgetsBelow.length;i++)
                 {
                    var val=this.widgetsBelow[i].config.propertyToRender;
                        console.log("propertyToRender:"+val);

                        console.log("val.."+ currentItem[i].val);



                 }

                 </script>
```

Two JSON arrays have been defined .When I try append one's output to another input  its showing undefined.propertyToRender is displaying  values but currentItem[val] is coming as undefined.how to execute dynamic values in JS?

Comment: Use like: `console.log("val.."+ currentItem[i][val])`;

Comment: To expand - you can access an object property without knowing the property name dynamically by accessing it with array notation.

Comment: `Two JSON arrays have been defined` no two *arrays* have been defined. They contain plain JavaScript objects. Or object literals, if you want. [There is no JSON here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: console.log("val.."+ currentItem[i][val]) coming as undefined